# How to save feature value from histogram of LBP image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

I'm using **Local Binary Pattern** (`LBP`) to extract the features of group of images (*500 images in Training folder and 100 Images in Test folder*). Indeed, I had extracted these features successfully but I'm not sure whether they saved in correct way or not.

Here is a part of code that extract the features:

```
for x = 1:total_images
% Specify images names with full path and extension    
full_name= fullfile(test_set, filenames(x).name);

% Read images from Training folder
I2 = imread(full_name);
I3=I2;
m=size(I2,1);
n=size(I2,2);

for i=2:m-1
    for j=2:n-1
        c=I2(i,j);
        I3(i-1,j-1)=I2(i-1,j-1)>c;
        I3(i-1,j)=I2(i-1,j)>c;
        I3(i-1,j+1)=I2(i-1,j+1)>c; 
        I3(i,j+1)=I2(i,j+1)>c;
        I3(i+1,j+1)=I2(i+1,j+1)>c; 
        I3(i+1,j)=I2(i+1,j)>c; 
        I3(i+1,j-1)=I2(i+1,j-1)>c; 
        I3(i,j-1)=I2(i,j-1)>c;
        LBP (i,j) =I3(i-1,j-1)*2^7+I3(i-1,j)*2^6+I3(i-1,j+1)*2^5+ ...
            I3(i,j+1)*2^4+I3(i+1,j+1)*2^3+I3(i+1,j)*2^2+ ...
            I3(i+1,j-1)*2^1+I3(i,j-1)*2^0;
    end
end

featureMatrix {x} = hist(LBP,0:255); 

end
```

By using this code, I get `LBP` features of all images but I'm not sure about saving them correctly in a matrix. How to save feature value from this histogram of `LBP` image? I want to store this value for each image.

`featureMatrix` is a matrix that data will stored in. It should be consist of 500 rows, each row should has all features of each image.

Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: There is now `extractLBPFeatures` function in MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extractlbpfeatures.html

Answer (score 1):

you should initialize the feature matrix before entering the outer loop (if you could know the size of LBP):

`featureMatrix = zeros(total_images,size_LBP); % where size_LBP is the number of columns of LBP.`

then replace `featureMatrix {x} = hist(LBP,0:255);` in the loop with:

`featureMatrix(x,:) = hist(LBP,255);`

I hope this works for you!